# unable to call a defined function, invalid syntax on a line i have used before in the code

Tags: python, function, syntax, fastapi

```
@app.get("/drogaraia")
def scraperaia(urlbase="https://www.drogaraia.com.br/medicamentos",maximodepaginas=10):
            
    listaprincipal= []
    pagina=2
    contador=1

    while pagina<maximodepaginas:
        testeurl= ((urlbase)+".html?p="+str(pagina))
        page = requests.get(testeurl)
        results= BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
        remedios = results.find_all("div",class_="container")
        
        for remedio in remedios:
            try:
                link=(remedio.find("a", class_="show-hover"))['href'] 
                preco=remedio.find(class_="price").getText().strip() 
                titulo=(remedio.find("a", class_="show-hover")).getText()
                categoria=urlbase.rsplit('/',1)[-1]
                listaremedio=[{'link':link,'preco':preco,'titulo':titulo,'categoria':categoria}]
                listaprincipal.extend(listaremedio)
            
            except:
                pass
                     
            contador=contador+1
            
        pagina=pagina+1
    return(listaprincipal)


@app.get("/drogaraia/medicamentos/monitores-e-testes/teste-de-controle-glicemicos")
scraperaia(urlbase="https://www.drogaraia.com.br/medicamentos/monitores-e-testes/teste-de-controle-glicemicos",maximodepaginas=10)
```

Error message here:

```
scraperaia(urlbase="https://www.drogaraia.com.br/medicamentos/monitores-e-testes/teste-de-controle-glicemicos",maximodepaginas=10)
    ^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't see how it can be wrong syntax. I have tried not assigning the variables inside the `scraperaia()` function, like so:

```
urlbase="https://www.drogaraia.com.br/medicamentos/monitores-e-testes/teste-de-controle-glicemicos"
maximodepaginas=10
scraperaia(urlbase,maximodepaginas)
```

and it still doesnt work.

Comment: The decorator (`@app.get`) needs to be in front of a function decorator (it's shorthand for a function that wraps another function, and should be applied to the function definition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two lines of your provided code are wrong. You need to use `def` to define a function.

Comment: i dont want to define it again, i want to call the same "scraperaia" function i already defined above.

Comment: Then you should define it as a separatie function all together, without a path decorator. Then, you can define your paths and define you path operations functions, in which you can call the generic function above.

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple routes bound to the same function. If you would like to know which route was used, you can use the `Request` object to get the request URL path (see documentation [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/) and [here](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#url)). Working example below:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/store")
@app.get("/store/monitors-and-tests")
def main(request: Request, baseurl: str = "https://someurl", maxpages: int = 10):
    return {"Called from": request.url.path}
```

For more solutions, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715292/17865804) as well.