# FastAPI GET endpoint returns "405 method not allowed" response

Tags: python, rest, fastapi, http-status-code-405

A `GET` endpoint in FastAPI is returning correct result, but returns `405 method not allowed` when `curl -I` is used. This is happening with all the `GET` endpoints. As a result, the application is working, but health check on application from a load balancer is failing.

Any suggestions what could be wrong?

**code**

```
@app.get('/health')
async def health():
    """
    Returns health status
    """
    return JSONResponse({'status': 'ok'})
```

**result**

```
curl http://172.xx.xx.xx:8080
```

[image]

**return header**

```
curl -I http://172.xx.xx.xx:8080
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FastAPI rejecting POST request from javascript code but not from a 3rd party request application (insomnia)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71404138/fastapi-rejecting-post-request-from-javascript-code-but-not-from-a-3rd-party-req)

Comment: Please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71568250/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693108/17865804).

Comment: @Chris thanks. all your suggestions here are pertaining to PUT request being passed as GET. My request is GET to begin with and despite that i am seeing issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`curl -I`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-I) option (which is used in the example you provided) is the same as using `curl --head` and performrs an [HTTP `HEAD`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) request, in order to fetch the *headers* **only** (not the *body*/*content* of the resource):

> The **HTTP `HEAD` method** requests the [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) that would be
> returned if the `HEAD` request's URL was instead requested with the
> HTTP [`GET`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) method. For example, if a URL might produce a large
> download, a `HEAD` request could read its [`Content-Length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length) header
> to check the filesize without actually downloading the file.

The requested resource/endpoint you are trying to call supports only `GET` requests; hence, the [`405 Method Not Allowed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) response status code, which indicates that the server knows the request method, but the target resource **doesn't** support this method.

To demonstrate this, have a look at the example below:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
async def main():
    return {'Hello': 'World'}
```

**Test** using Python requests (similar result is obtained using `curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8000`)

```py
import requests

# Making a GET request
# r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000')
  
# Making a HEAD request
r = requests.head('http://127.0.0.1:8000')
  
# check status code for response received
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
  
# print headers of request
print(r.headers)
  
# checking if request contains any content
print(r.content)
```

**Output** (indicating by the [`allow` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Allow) which request methods are supported by the requested resource):

```json
405 Method Not Allowed
{'date': 'Sun, 12 Mar 2023', 'server': 'uvicorn', 'allow': 'GET', 'content-length': '31', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
b''
```

If, instead, you performed a `GET` request (in order to issue a `GET` request in the example above, uncomment the line for `GET` request and comment the one for `HEAD` request, or in `curl` use `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000`), the response would be as follows:

```json
200 OK
{'date': 'Sun, 12 Mar 2023', 'server': 'uvicorn', 'content-length': '17', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
b'{"Hello":"World"}'
```

## Solutions

To make a FastAPI endpoint supporting more than one [HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) (e.g., both `GET` and `HEAD` requests), the following solutions are available.

### Solution 1

Cretate two different functions with a decorator refering to the request method for which they should be called, i.e., `@app.head()` and `@app.get()`, or, if the logic of the function is the same for both the request methods, then simply add a decorator for each request method that you would like the endpoint to support to the same function. For instance:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.head('/')
@app.get('/')
async def main():
    return {'msg': 'Hello World'}
```

### Solution 2

Use the [`@app.api_route()`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/392ffaae43d11838ece62acfa8bb50e5d2f5ca05/fastapi/applications.py#L334) decorator, which allows you to define the set of supported request methods for the endpoint. For example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
 
@app.api_route('/', methods=['GET', 'HEAD'])
async def main():
    return {'msg': 'Hello World'}
```

##### Output

Both solutions above would respond as follows (when a `HEAD` request is issued by a client):

```json
200 OK
{'date': 'Sun, 12 Mar 2023', 'server': 'uvicorn', 'content-length': '17', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
b''
```

In both solutions, if you would like to distinguish between the methods used to call the endpoint, you could use the `.method` attribute of the  `Request` object. For instance:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()
 
@app.api_route('/', methods=['GET', 'HEAD'])
async def main(request: Request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print('GET method was used')
    elif request.method == 'HEAD':
        print('HEAD method was used')
    
    return {'msg': 'Hello World'}
```

---

**Note 1:** In the test example using Python requests above, please avoid calling the `json()` method on the response when performing a `HEAD` request, as a response to a `HEAD` method request does not normally have a body, and it would raise an exception, if attempted calling `r.json()`—see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77858325/17865804) for more details. Instead, use `print(r.content)`, as demonstrated in the example above on `HEAD` requests, if you would like to check whether or not there is a response body.

**Note 2:** The `405 Method Not Allowed` response may also be caused by other reasons—see related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71414202/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71568250/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693108/17865804).

Answer (score 1):

FastAPI has a [bug](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1773).  It allows a `GET` method on that path, not a `HEAD` method.

The `curl -I` option is equivalent to the `--head`. It sends an [HTTP `HEAD` request](https://reqbin.com/req/c-tmyvmbgu/curl-head-request-example#:%7E:text=To%20send%20a%20HEAD%20request,still%20respond%20to%20GET%20requests.).

Because the FastAPI server does not support the HEAD method, only the GET it correctly responds with a [HTTP-405](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405).

There is a workaround - to add manually defined `@app.head()`.