# FastAPI returns 405 Method Not Allowed response when mounting a StaticFiles instance

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, fastapi

I have this FastAPI  application

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.responses import FileResponse

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/a")
async def read_index():
    return FileResponse('static/index.html')


@app.get("/a/b")
def download():
    return "get"


@app.post("/a/b")
def ab():
    return "post"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and in `static/index.html` I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <form method="post" action="/a/b" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
          <p>Download:</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Download"/>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

I send a get request to `http://127.0.0.1:8001/a` and click on the `download` button it loads, it returns "get"

However, I change the application to

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/a", StaticFiles(directory="static", html=True))



@app.get("/a/b")
def download():
    return "get"


@app.post("/a/b")
def ab():
    return "post"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

with the same HTML file, I click on the download button, and I get `detail: "Method Not Allowed"` because it is doing `INFO:     127.0.0.1:58109 - "POST /b HTTP/1.1" 405 Method Not Allowed`

I want to use mount becuase I want to put js and css files there as well, to be used by the index.html file. how should I do this?

Comment: Please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74498663/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715292/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71741617/17865804)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve the problem is to register all `a/blahblah` routes first and `a` then. Just change order:

```py
@app.get("/a/b")
def ...

@app.post("/a/b")
def ...

app.mount("/a", StaticFiles(directory="static", html=True))
```

However, in this case file with name `b` uploaded to `static` folder will be inaccessible. Becasue `@app.get("/a/b")` will be called first. I recommend to redesign routes structure if you want to avoid this behavior.

**[Here is a full detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/13946204)**

Comment: Thanks, I had read that post but could not figure out what to do. this answer helped me solve my problem