# Python FastAPI question: How do I achieve route aliasing in FASTAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I just started learning about FastAPI and I have this issue where I need your kind help.

Let's say I am creating a page based on some image IDs (img001, img002, ... etc.) which are saved in a database with relevant information like location, country, date, path, resolution etc. There are 1500+ images.

I want to write a script index.py under /photo directory which is like `http://localhost:8000/photo/?id=img001` which will read the database table for imageID = img001 and will show all the above information/metadata for that image.

I would like to automatically create aliases like below:

```
http://localhost:8000/myimage/001    -> http://localhost:8000/photo/?id=img001
http://localhost:8000/myimage/002    -> http://localhost:8000/photo/?id=img002
http://localhost:8000/myimage/003    -> http://localhost:8000/photo/?id=img003
```

There is a separate system to add the images into the database and that is dynamic and anytime a new image can come so I cannot configure and populate these aliases beforehand - they need to be dynamically aliased like above.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any mechanism to do this kind of "aliasing". I would suggest moving all endpoint logic to a helper function (e.g. `get_image_by_id`), and then having two endpoints that both call that function.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by two endpoints? BTW: This is possible by routing with regex match in languages like PHP with Laravel framework. Does FastAPI offer that kind of feature?

Comment: You can have a route that redirects the client to the format you want: `@app.get("/myimage/{image_id}", response_class=RedirectResponse), def redirect_path(image_id): return f"/photo/?id=img{image_id}"`- you should also validate the format of `image_id` a bit more, but this shows the concept.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71408420/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715292/17865804) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RedirectResponse` like below.

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode

@app.get("/myimage/{image_id}")
def your_view(image_id):
    qparams = dict(req.query_params)
    qstring = urlencode(qparams)
    return RedirectResponse(f"/photo/?id=img{image_id}&{qstring}")
```

Ref: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/?h=redirectresponse#redirectresponse

Comment: Thank you! Let me try this. One further question I have is:
  
Will it be possible to route all subsequent parameters as well? What I mean is: let's say your suggestion can route ...
    http://localhost:8000/myimage/001    -> http://localhost:8000/photo/?id=img00

But what if there are other params like  /?id=img00&param1=value1
Will the above function 
    def your_view( )
Can do the routing as....

http://localhost:8000/myimage/001/?param1=value1    -> http://localhost:8000/photo/?id=img00&param1=value1

Or do I need to write separate function for this RedirectResponse ?